# Hide a HTML button based on a if-condition

Tags: html, list, jsp, if-statement, button

I have a JSP page which includes a button called "Download".I want to hide this button based on a if-condition.

The Download button is meant to generate and download PDF onclick of it.

I have a List that is being fetched from the Controller and if this list is empty, I want to hide the "Download" button on the JSP page.

This is my button,

```
<button type="button" class="btn bg-red waves-effect" onclick="ExportPdf()">Download</button>
```

I want to hide the button if the List is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display when list isn't empty:

```
<% if (!list.isEmpty()){ %>
<button type="button" class="btn bg-red waves-effect" onclick="ExportPdf()">Download</button>  
<% } %>
```

For example if you fetch list from attribute

```
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("listName");
```